# unable to read a file in c language. it creates a new file instead of reading it

Tags: c

I have creates a file in directory and want to read it in. I am using the following code to open and read a file in C-Language. But it creates a new file instead of reading the old file.

```
int main()
{
   FILE * file;
   file = fopen ("file", "r+");
   //file reading code
   fclose(file);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: check premissions to file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using **'r+'** mode to open the file. It creates a new file if not already exist in the directory. see the following code for your help.

```
int main()
{
   FILE * file;
   file = fopen ("file", "r");
   if(file !== NULL)
       // to do file reading code
   else 
       printf("error in reading file");
   fclose(file);
   return(0);
}
```

also check the file name that you are using in fopen() function.It is case sensitive and also check the extension of that file e.g; .txt or .data or what ever. e.g;

```
file = fopen ("File.txt", "r");
```

Comment: `fopen` itself isn't case sensitive or insensitive. That's determined by the underlying OS/file system. IIRC, e.g. DOS with FAT is case-insensitive and Linux has mount options for vfat ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to read from a file then open it for reading, i.e. mode `r` (notice no `+`):

```
file = fopen ("file", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answers given but you can also additionally check if file is present or not. Something as below. In case program does not recognize the file it will let you know. Avoid using r+ in case you want to read an already existing file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `gets`, especially to beginners. And a minor note: The newline at the end of `perror` is odd, the string passed is output followed by a colon (`:`), a space and the error message (and a newline).